# Can't mount /boot/efi partition under install

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, uefi, 16.04, ibm

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Server on a IBM server x3550 M4 with ServerRAID (RAID1) but I have a few problems.

Under the partition menu I get this error.

[image: Ubuntu efi error]
We have used Ubuntu before on our IBM servers but somehow that doesn't work any more. Its it Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on the picture, but got the same error with Ubuntu 14.04.

Any help would be nice, thanks :)

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the output of the following two commands: `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda` and `sudo blkid /dev/sda1`. It may also be necessary to see the partitioning screen in the installer. Trying to manually mount the ESP outside of the installer may provide a more helpful error message, too.